# Conversion of a Sheridan DBGrid to a winforms datagriidview control can't find equalavent of bookmark property

Tags: vb.net, bookmarks

I am trying to get rid of the Sheridan DBGrid control that we used when we were in vb6.  We did a conversion from vb6 to vb.net and now just have ActiveX controls left that we have to replace because they are no longer supported and are not native .net code.  We are now in vb.net and we have an activex wrapper in .net which inherits from a Sheridan DBGrid.  We are trying to get rid of all ActiveX controls and have this DBGrid to replace.

Sheridan's DBGrid has this bookmark functionality that I am not sure know we can find the equalivant for in the .net 3.5 framework.  Does any one know what I can replace the bookmark functionality with in dot net.  I am using VB.net.  Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the .Bookmark property of the Sheridan control, but if you want a reference to the datarow corresponding to the selected row, you can use:

```
Dim drw As DataRow = DirectCast(dgv1.SelectedRows(0).DataBoundItem, DataRowView).Row
```

This assumes that the .DataSource of the grid is a datatable.